Surviving a Difficult Client While Job Hunting
I've been with my company for over three years and was promoted to manager last year. We focus on a few large clients, and as the manager of my engineering group, I handle interactions with one of our key clients, including negotiating contracts and deliverables. While I can manage the client relationship, the real challenge comes from a representative at the client company.
This individual frequently agrees to deliverables during our discussions but then changes his mind without notifying me. He often creates conflicting agreements with others—both internally and externally—without including me in the conversation. His disorganization and dismissive behavior complicate collaboration. For instance, I was reprimanded in a meeting for challenging a technically unfeasible request and later received internal criticism for "pressuring" him.
The reality is that there’s a significant knowledge gap between us, which makes communication difficult. I try to gauge his understanding and clarify things with good intentions, but I often face negative reactions. It feels like he’s more concerned about his image than about actually getting the work done.
Additionally, he often excludes me from important meetings and withholds information. I’ve tried to follow up on these issues, but it hasn’t led to any improvements; in fact, it seems to have made things worse. I feel I can no longer work effectively with him, but I worry that declining to engage with him could have serious repercussions, including the risk of losing my job.
I’m feeling incredibly frustrated and stressed, which has prompted me to start looking for a new job. I know I’m wasting the opportunity for a stable career in this company, which is disappointing. But the thought of spending several more years managing this individual is overwhelming. Unfortunately, I know that finding a new job will take time, and I may have to endure this situation for another year.
My question is: how can I avoid conflicts with this person and reduce my stress levels in the meantime? I’ve communicated my concerns internally, but it hasn’t resulted in any changes. My boss insists for me to I find ways to work around the issues. I’ve tried documenting our meetings and agreements, but he continues to disregard them. I would appreciate any ideas or strategies you might have.

So, how long will it take you to leave? 2 weeks notice? 20 months notice? 4 years? Or is this India with all the hassle of relieving letters? Leaving will help the stress...

I don't think the notice is a problem. Finding another job in my field is. It takes time.
I am not planning to be jobless.

“For instance, I was reprimanded in a meeting for challenging a technically unfeasible request and later received internal criticism for "pressuring" him.” - You challenged the client in front of the client or behind closed doors to your manager (or whomever reprimanded you). I am not sure you have a choice but to “make it work”, the client is the client, and apparently this particularly large client will require more work to “make it work”

@Donald, if I am the client, I would rather hear it sooner than later that my request is for the impossible. Then I might have time on my end to see what can be done to get everything into a "possible" state.

That client representative (CR) is not only a burr under your saddle, but also a detrimental force in your client's company. You indicate that you would like to do better at handling this client account. You may have missed that he is doing an execrable job of handling his supplier account.
Microsoft is one of the most successful companies in business history, and the Microsoft sales handbook covers this exact situation. You must make CR's boss -- and, if possible, everyone in his chain of command -- aware of how bad a job he is doing.
You have to schmooze with somebody that outranks CR, and sell over CR's head. If you don't have the experience for this, enlist your company's sales force to guide you.
Emphasize the knowledge gap. Suggest solutions that are obviously better than CR's. Document how much money CR is costing his employer by his incompetent fumbling.
Your goal in all this is to reduce CR's credibility and influence within his company to the point where you can get somebody else to sign off on your requirements and deliverables. Better, to get CR replaced as your point of contact. (Or even to get CR fired, what do you care.)
Now you may say that all this is outside your authority. I say: get your sales force to do it. What are they for anyway.
Or you may say that all this is outside your comfort zone. I say: so is leaving your job.
Or you may say that all this is dishonest, unethical, and borderline criminal. I say: Microsoft Windows.
Of course you can do all this while job searching. Come to think of it, you probably should.

As somebody who deals with a contractor engineer who thinks they are the smartest person in the room, and while I am definitely not the smartest guy in the room, I also know this individual definitely isn’t either. My point trying to burn the bridge with the CR on it might backfire. What you propose could backfire on the author

IMHO, first step would be to find out the connection of this CR in the client company
This type of behavior usually indication of "connected" individual
you may need to immerse yourself in the internals of the client company and  find a person who can help you with "dislodging" the CR
In case it will prove impossible, perhaps you should invite one of your big bosses to sit in or listen on a few of the meeting where CR show himself in the "best" light
Granted, all of it may be for nothing, very unlikely that your bosses would like to loose the key client over some communication grievances

I feel compelled to agree with you. In fact I agreed with you six hours before you did.

Suggestion: try telling your boss that you are getting completely frustrated with this person, and you don't know how long it's going to be before you respond to him in a way that might damage the business relationship, so can you be assigned elsewhere and make him someone else's problem for a while?
If they say nobody but you can handle that account, I would take that as permission to ask that your your performance evaluation and your next raise reflect that. Being paid more to deal with assholes doesn't make it any more pleasant, but at least shows that manglement appreciates the effort.
Meanwhile, polish up your resume and start circulating it. Finding a new job takes a lot longer if you never start.

Polish up your resume by all means, but if interviewing you and I got a hint of this type of performance issue, there would be some awkward questions for you. Because wherever you go, you'll find this sort of person.
Firstly, you need the backing and support of your managers to handle this contract.
In any case where work is decided, a change request document MUST be issued. If the work is then no longer needed, that change request MUST be rescinded by the client to avoid charges for future work. If they change the spec, a new change request is needed.
This is a standard method of operation in many companies, and provides a solid audit trail of bad workmanship by the client.
For meetings; make sure that your people KNOW that you are in charge of this account. You should be present for most meetings; any that you are not in should have minutes written of any decisions, and no work is to start without your signoff (and the change request document, as above).
If you're the only person who can handle this account, then make sure that you're the only person who IS handling that account. Which is why I said initially; you need buyin and support from your superiors.
